# Passing variable from jQuery to PHP on the same page

Tags: php, jquery

Please bear up with me, I'm new to PHP. I'm using a mixture of `PHP` and `jQuery` on the same page. I need to pass variables from `jQuery` to `PHP`. All examples I came across describe how to pass variables to a `PHP` file on the server which I don't want. So far I manged to convert object to JSON using jQuery $.toJSON();
My question is: is it possible to pass jQuery data to php code if both `jQuery` and `PHP` reside on the same page?

Here is my code so far:

```
var myObject = {name: 'Tomas', age: 38};
var encoded = $.toJSON( myObject);
var name = $.evalJSON( encoded ).name;
var version = $.evalJSON(encoded).age;
```

Comment: Simple answer no, because php is run _before_ the page even loads. but you may trigger some sort of save (session/cookie etc.) of variables on the page. A very simple solution is to put your php inside an image or script which is dynamically loaded

Comment: You can't do that.. php runs on server and jquery run's on browser

Comment: I'm aware that php runs on the server, but we can still run php functions and the php data will be available during the session.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible since PHP is not a client side script but rather a server side script. What that means is that by the time the data is given to the client the PHP script would have most likely already finished running. The following demonstrates the relationship between PHP and JavaScript:

> Server -> PHP -> Client (Browser) -> Javascript

Therefore, it is impossible to have javascript communicate to PHP on the same page. What you can do is use Ajax to call a server side file like you said - but I'm afraid that is as much as you can do in terms of PHP and JavaScript Communication